# How to click an overlay popup in android using Appium when it's Node details are not shown by Uiautomator Viewer

Tags: java, android, automation, appium

In edittext box when I enter some value then an overlay pop-up is displayed which need to be clicked to move further in application navigation. But the concern is that Uiautomator viewer doesn't show node details of overlay pop-up.
[image]

It would be great if someone can help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If the element can not been found in page source, you can:

1. Click via the coordinate of screen.
2. Add accessibility for the element to improve the testability of the app:
   [The android AccessibilityNodeProvider docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/accessibility/AccessibilityNodeProvider)

Hope can help.